# SlidingDrawer and Imageview Android

Tags: android, click, imageview, handle, slidingdrawer

I have an imageview as :

```
    <ImageView 
   android:id="@+id/oyna"
   android:src="@drawable/oyna"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and after this,I have a slidingdrawer as:

```
<SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:topOffset="50dip" >
```

I want to click the imageview and open the slidingdrawer.When I put id of imageview for handle,there will be exception.What can I do?

Comment: If I put imageview code in slidingdrawer code,image will be bottom of the screen.But I want imageview seems on the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" >

    <!-- set the id of the imageview to be handle -->
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```